# Checking For null in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq

In the code below I am trying to get the null, empty string, and source components out of a List. I have not tested this code yet but my intuition tells me it will break when filtering the List for source and empty string if it comes by a null value.

I tried to extract the null values first, but I am still filtering the base List. How can I re-write this code to accomplish what I am trying to do in the best way?

```
List<LineItem> nullList=itemsList.Where(s => s[Constants.ProductSource] == null)
                                 .ToList();

NALineItems = itemsList.Where(s => s[Constants.ProductSource] == source 
                                   || s[Constants.ProductSource] == String.Empty)
                       .ToList();

NALineItems = nullList.Union(NALineItems).ToList();
```

s[Constants.ProductSource] is an attachment property to Microsoft ECommerce PurchaseOrder object. Its basically another property of an object.

Comment: "I have not tested this code yet but my intuition tells me it will break" That means you're asking this question prematurely.

Comment: Are you aware of String.IsNullOrEmpty ?

Comment: Does `itemsList` contain arrays? Whats this `s[Constants.ProductSource]`?

Comment: We should know if our code is gonna break in these cases without testing first. That is partially what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't agree - if you have some code already go ahead and try it out, write some tests (write the tests that you suppose might break first!)  - it has value and the next time you come across a similar thing you will know what to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on "*I am trying to get the null, empty string, and source components out of a List*" I assume you mean you want a list with these 3 specific values.

```
var allItems = itemsList
                 .Where(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s[Constants.ProductSource])
                             || s[Constants.ProductSource] == source)
                 .ToList()
```

Comment: I think you meant "|| s[Constants.ProductSource] == source" with == rather than =, otherwise strange things may happen.

Comment: Yes thanks for the correction!  Actually it wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you cannot combine the expression into one?  I would also add a check that the key exists in the dictionary:

```
List<LineItem> NALineItems = itemsList.Where(s =>
    s.ContainsKey(Constants.ProductSource) && (
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(s[Constants.ProductSource]) ||
        s[Constants.ProductSource] == source))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Interesting..Where is the dictionary defined? I am not aware of this

Comment: I am assuming that `itemslist` is a list of Dictionaries from your code, but it could also be a list of lists (if Constants.ProductSource is an integer).  I'd have to see more context.